# How to get kubernetes / minikube env variable in vue js

Tags: python, vue.js, kubernetes, minikube

I have a python app and vue-js app in minikube. I have tried to do a post to python app service by mentioning "python-app-service" in URL, but still, vue js applies that as a literal "python-app-service" instead of IP address.

let say this is my deployment called `python-server`:

`spec:
  containers:
    - image: python-server:latest
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      name: python-servier
  ports:
    - containerPort: 8001
      name: python-server`

and my service called `python-server-service`

`spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8001
      targetPort: 8001`

In the other hand, I have a similar kind of deploymet and service for vue js.

Now I want to do axios post request in vue js towards the `python-server` :

```
axios.post('python-server-service'+'/api/new/post', 
this.name, // the data to post
{ headers: {
  'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }
}).then(response => ....);
```

instead of this :

```
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:3030/api/new/post', 
this.name, // the data to post
{ headers: {
  'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }
}).then(response => ....);
```

But unfortunately the vueJS will not resolve my `python-server-service` and put it as literal string "python-server-service".

How can I possibly get the python-app-service IP address in vuejs running in minikube?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that would make the most sense is to use a Kubernetes [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and use the hostname with the Kubernetes [DNS nomenclature](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/): `<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<exposed-port>`. Since both pods are in the same cluster it can be [ClusterIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) type of service.

The issue with IP addresses is that they are not fixed in a Kubernetes cluster (even minikube), but for testing you can always get the IP address of the pod like this:

```
$ kubectl get pod <pod-name> -o=jsonpath='{.status.podIP}'
```

Comment: I havr done that, but vuejs or any other app is reading it as literal string. For example url="mypythonapp" is red as mypythonapp instead resolving it to the app's Ip adress

Comment: You didn't explain what you had done on your question... what does your deployment look like for both you python and vue?